# Getting pixel color from a UIView or a UIImageView which is 3D rotated

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rotation, uigraphicscontext

I have code that gets pixel color from a view.

The code works well every time except when I rotate my view either X-axis or Y-axis wise.

The code also works well with Z-axis, but because X-axis and Y-axis works on the layer maybe that's the reason why I am not getting the pixel color as expected

Here's my code that I use to get pixel color

```
func getPixelColor(_ point: CGPoint) -> UIColor? {
    let pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: 4)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let context = CGContext(data: pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue).rawValue)
    context?.translateBy(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)
    if let context = context {
        layer.render(in: context)
    }
    let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(Double(pixel[0]) / 255.0), green: CGFloat(Double(pixel[1]) / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(Double(pixel[2]) / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(Double(pixel[3]) / 255.0))
    return color
}
```

What changes should be made to get the correct pixel color even with X-axis and Y-axis rotation

Thanks!

Comment: what is point value at call time?

Comment: @SPatel Thanks for the response! Point value is the point that I get by applying pan gesture to the view